# groupby agg (return the same value for selected columns while others sum)

Tags: python, sum, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I have Panda's `groupby` function, and I would like the Name and Phone columns to just copy the values, while for the Income it would sum.
But this lambda function doesn't work for me

```
df.groupby('ID').agg({'Name' : lambda x: x,
                 'Income' : 'sum',
                 'Phone' : lambda x: x})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
df.groupby('ID').agg({'Name' : 'first',
                 'Income' : 'sum',
                 'Phone' : 'first'})
```